# Paperclip Error: NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've had a rails install with Paperclip working just fine for a while now and in a recent deploy it has broken.  I believe it coincided with a gemfile update, because nothing else on the machine has changed.  The error is:

```
Command :: file -b --mime :file
[paperclip] Error while determining content type: Command 'file -b --mime :file' returned 1. Expected 0
```

This is on a png file that I've verified to be valid.  When I run 'file -b --mime' on the image I get:

```
image/png; charset=binary
```

I also get this afterwards:

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h :file
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/song_waveform_3010520121008-23335-165xag4.png20121008-23335-j8e18p is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

I did a which file and it gave me /usr/bin so I tried setting the Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/" in production.rb with no change.

I can't think of why this could be happening.  Perhaps it's not pointing to the right directory?  I'm a bit lost here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by the API change in Cocaine 4 which Paperclip has not caught up to yet. Try using the earlier version of Cocaine by inserting this line into your Gemfile:

```
gem "cocaine", "= 0.3.2"
```

Comment: You've certainly saved me hours of time.  Thank you.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed since paperclip 3.3: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1038

Comment: My error was instead fix simply by `brew upgrade ImageMagick`

Comment: As of January 2, 2014, Paperclip 3.5.2 requires cocaine ~> 0.5.3.

Answer (score 4):

add gem "cocaine", "= 0.3.2"

then bundle install  message

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "cocaine":   In Gemfile:
    paperclip (~> 3.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      cocaine (~> 0.4.0) x86-mingw32

    cocaine (0.3.2)
```

Comment: Try using this: gem "cocaine", "= 0.3.2" 
gem "paperclip", "= 3.0.4"

Answer (score 2):

it used to work fine for pdf and images, tried out for an hour or so, followed everything I googled later the problem was found in my model  has_attached_file :attachment,

> :styles => {:original=> "125x125#"}

had to comment this line, and it worked for other attachments like docx or odt etc..

Answer (score 0):

For those who have a similar problem, be sure to double check that ImageMagick is installed, or make sure you do not use the 'styles' option.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using OSX + MAMP + Passenger + Paperclip and after setting the command_path and ensuring imagemagick was properly installed via brew, properly setting the temp and upload directories for passenger to something writable, it still wouldn't work!

The solution was to edit the envvars file for MAMP in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars and comment out the export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH line.

That is, change the line that says

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to

```
# export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then restart MAMP and feel the elation when your images are properly uploading/resizing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after upgrading to Mavericks.
I ended up solving the problem by unlinking jpeg and re-linking it

```
brew unlink jpeg
brew link jpeg
```

And everything worked fine. BTW, running Paperclip 4.1

Answer (score -1):

After all your changes, don't forget to restart your server...!